# Maiuscola per la parola Sibilla

Tags: nouns, orthography, capitalization

Non riesco a capire il motivo per cui in molte fonti trovo scritto "Sibilla" con la lettera maiuscola. Teoricamente dovrebbe essere un nome comune visto che le sacerdotesse erano più di una e quindi essere scritto in minuscolo. Vorrei capire quando metterlo con la lettera maiuscola e perché.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quando il termine è in minuscolo indica una categoria, come [nella frase, tratta da Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilla)

> Le sibille erano vergini dotate di virtù profetiche ispirate da un dio (solitamente Apollo), ed erano in grado di fornire responsi e fare predizioni, per lo più in forma oscura o ambivalente.

Talvolta invece il termine viene utilizzato come titolo onorifico,  come nel caso della  *Sibilla Eritrea*, la *Sibilla Cumana* e la *Sibilla Delfica*

Tale titolo trae probabilmente la sua origine dal nome proprio *Sibilla*. Sempre da Wikipedia:

> In origine Sibilla (dal greco Sibylla) era un nome proprio di persona. Probabilmente era quello di una delle sibille più antiche, la Sibilla Libica, come ci attesta Pausania.

Answer (score 5):

Come si può leggere sul vocabolario [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sibilla/), quando ci si rivolge ad una delle veggenti della Grecia Antica, si è soliti usare la lettera maiuscola, mentre nell'utilizzo scherzoso del termine, ove si indica una comune indovina, verrà preferita l'iniziale minuscola. Ad esempio:

> La campitura sulla Sibilla Cumana

oppure

> La campitura sulle sibille

Comment: Ma allora per esempio io ho un dipinto con delle sibille che sono effettivamente delle sibille greche però quando non cito il loro nome per esempio: "la campitura sulla sibilla" scrivo sibilla o Sibilla.